# Uninstalling "LiveWallpaper"

Tags: uninstall

Recently I downloaded an application by the name of "LiveWallpaper" from Microsoft Store. I cannot find it anywhere in my files. I want to delete it from my computer. (I'm on Windows 10 Home)

Comment: Right click > Uinstall.[How To Uninstall Microsoft Store Apps](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-store-apps/)

Comment: And if you really want to delete it from your PC, you can either use PowerShell (https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/uninstall-restore-windows-10-builtin-apps) or a third-party such as Revo Uninstaller (free: https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/). It'll do it for you.

Comment: @Didier that is not really good advise, and should only be used in case a normal uninstall fails. OP does not seem to know the difference between apps and programs, and that you need to uninstall apps from a different place than programs.

Comment: I don't know what the OP "seems to know" or not, I just provide a way to get rid of the app once and for all. The OP can reinstall it at a later date from the Windows Store if he/she so chooses, but depending on the app in question, it might save some space to actually remove it from the HDD or SSD, not just hide it from sight... I stand by my comment. Feel free to remove it; wouldn't be the first time, won't be the last, I'm sure.

Comment: @Didier I'm not suggesting to just hide the shortcut, I'm suggesting to use the UWP platform's own method of removing it. I've seen it too often that the entire windows store stops working when people play with uninstallers or powershell scripts without knowing what they're doing. Yes, in most cases it'll work fine, but should only be used when there is no other way. As for removing comments, I'm not a moderator, just a very experienced user. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apps and Programs are not the same. An App is a program that runs on the UWP platform. As such, it is also installed in a different way and behaves similarly as to how apps work on your phone.

Its files are stored in a location that is not accessible to a user, and as such you need to remove it using its designed uninstall button.

If an App does not work correctly, you can also reinstall or clear its cache the same way you can fix problems on a phone, except... this is build specifically for Windows 8 and up.

Right-click the start button and press Apps and Features (the first item in the list) to bring you to all your installed Apps and Programs. The app you want to uninstall will be in this list. Search for it, and click the uninstall button to remove it from the computer.

Do note, this is not the same as the Control Panel, Programs and Features.